# Is there a way to rewrite just a directory, so that all articles within that directory redirect 1 level up?

Tags: regex, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I have a site `http://www.mysite.com/blog/category/post/` and I need to redirect it to `http://www.mysite.com/category/post` ie, I want to remove the `blog` from my URL. Is there a way to do it using permanent redirects in .htaccess?

**Thank you very much!**

Answer (score 0):

Enable mod_rewrite and .htaccess through `httpd.conf` and then put this code in your `.htaccess` under `DOCUMENT_ROOT` directory:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^blog(/.*|)$ $1 [L,R=301,NC]
```